# User does not have required permissions in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm getting the error below when I try and access SSRS on SQL Server 2008 R2

I'm not sure how many others have started using SQL 2008 R2 SSRS, but I am having an issue with getting the error below when I try and access the reports server url

**User does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed**

What I have tried:

I can access the url if I run IE as an administrator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you're able to log in to YourServer/Reports as an administrator, click Home in the top-right corner, then Folder Settings and New Role Assignment. Enter your user name and check a box for each role you want to grant yourself. Finally, click OK. You should now be able to browse folders without launching your browser with elevated privileges.

Don't forget to set the security at the site level **AND ** at the folder level. I hope that helps.